# Understanding aspects of Google Cloud Messaging - basic setup

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, httpserver

I have an android application that is designed to receive push notifications via GCM. When I initially designed the application, I used a "deprecated" tutorial (merely because it was one of the most in-depth I found) and my dev phone was running API 2.4, so I was able to get the service up and running without much issue.

Now, my development device is running Android version 4.4.2, so my goal is to "upgrade" my application to handle GCM properly for all devices (for now, lets ignore the fact that I'll have to differentiate how to handle Push Notifications depending on API level).

I attempted to follow the Android Developer tutorial for creating a demo client app for Google Cloud messaging, which can be found here. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

While I hate to sound like I want to ignore to smart coding practices, this official walk through was a little big in terms of scope (My application supports Phonegap, and while I think implementing native GCM is much easier than using the PushPlugin for Phonegap, I don't want to handle more than is absolutely necessary in my Java code)

As a last ditch effort, I simply downloaded the demo gcm code from the source they provided here: https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/?r=1ca8e646c517310e2d46a6a6eda74106b8084fc5

I attempted to import the gcm-demo-client application, and although I know my SENDER_ID, I don't understand anything about the SERVER_URL. The documentation provided by Android Developers talks very generally about HTTP vs. CCS, and I'm struggling to grasp where this server fits into the grand scheme of all that is Google Cloud Messaging.

Assuming I download the gcm-demo-server project directory they included (which seems to be some kind of Java Project), how do I host it? My previous deprecated GCM simply used a basic android application in which I would submit a form containing the device Registration Id, and a message with a title and context. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to import their demo-server into Eclipse (since Eclipse doesn't think it contains ANY project files), AND I cannot seem to understand how this server connects with my application in any capacity.

TL/DR Summary of questions:
1.) How can I go about "hosting" the gcm-demo-server from URL #2 above? 
2.) If I can just copy the Registration Id from my client app to the clipboard, can I just use my "android server" application to send my messages?
3.) Maybe it's just me, but I don't see anything resembling a Receiver class in the gcm-demo-client project directory, only a GcmIntentService. How can there be an intent when the application can't even properly handle messages?!

Thank you for your patience and help! 
(P.S. - I cannot provide any code- however since the code in question is merely the provided Android Developer GCM demo code, this hopefully won't be a big issue)

Answer (score 0):

1) There are many companies that offer server hosting services. You should choose one.

2) If you copy the registration Id manually, and hard code it in an application that serves as a "server", you don't need to host a real server, though that would only work in development. In production, assuming you'll have multiple users who install you app, you'll need a real server that receives and stores the registration IDs of all of them.

3) The demo client project you are referring to is old, and relies on a deprecated library (gcm.jar) which contains a default implementation of the BroadcastReceiver, which receives the messages from GCM server and starts the intent service. If you refer to the [current demo app](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/#gcm-client%2FGcmClient%2Fsrc%2Fmain), you'll find a BroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: Thank you @Eran , this cleared everything up. I had downoaded the current demo app without realizing where the project was (should have explored a little more!). Thank you very much! Got it up and working. Now comes the fun part - tearing up the old app and inserting the new code.

Answer (score 0):

The demo app might not work because it is a gradle project and you should preferably open it in Android Studio. That might be why it could not see it as an Android project at all.

I have recently started implementing GCM myself and it is not difficult at all. I am using AppEngine for holding the backend part of my app. In Android studio, there is a very quick and easy way to generate both the android client and the backend part including the cloud endpoints and even a web interface for sending the messages (you don't need to use it though).

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Maybe this is not a fully satisfying answer for you, but I found the code very much readable and I understood how this stuff works.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've been realizing that Android studio is really the way to go. I considered using App Engine as well for back-end stuff (having had previous experience) but I haven't really had time to sit down with it in a very long time. Looks like that will be my next place to look!